# Xamarin Android & iOS error logging

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, error-logging

How should I go about sending error logs (either stored in textfile or SQLite database) from a users phone to our company, while my only option of internet communication is e-mail? I'm prohibited to use a webserver due to security and management reasons.

It's possible the end-user is required to send over the error report using their default mailing app, but I can't resort to background mailing/smtp (iOS doesn't support this). So the user can simply discard the mail and we will never receive the error report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might not be the most efficient method - but if you're limited by your company policies then you can use SMTP - even if iOS itself does not support it as both Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android provides `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` (in the System.dll assembly).

Using this class you can send emails (at least when the network is available) to an application-configured server.

Comment: I guess I should resort to this then. I wasn't aware of the fact that .NET simply supports it. Thanks, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Xamarin Insights](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/insights/getting-started/) Xamarin Insights from Xamarin a cloud based error and performance dashboard

Xamarin Insights is available for use with applications on any of the following platforms:
•Xamarin.iOS (iOS 7+) ◦Insights only supports the Unified API.

•Xamarin.Android (API 14)
•Xamarin.Forms
•Windows 8.0
•Windows Phone & Windows 8.1 (winRT)